# What version of MSSQL gets installed and how to set named instance

Tags: 18.04, mssql

I see plenty of sites with instructions on installing mssql server on ubuntu, however, none of them seem to say what version of sql gets installed and the licensing terms.

For example, I plan to follow the instructions here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

However, I would like to know what version of sql server does this install and how do I use a named instance?

Comment: Check here [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#release-history](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#release-history)

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit.  I looked at that and at this as well: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15, but I still don't know what edition of sql is installed by the installation instructions.  What is the default edition that is installed? Express, standard,  developer?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the process and instructions on the microsoft website and basically the answer is that during the installation process you are presented with a selection of editions to pick from.[image]